# not case-sensitive column names in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm reflecting some tables of my MySQL database, and I'd like to apply filters on some of their columns.

```
meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
table_backlog= meta.tables['backlog']
all_filters = and_(and_(*all_filters),and_(table_backlog.c.month != "NULL",table_backlog.c.month != None))
```

But the problem is that sometimes the column name changes from `month` to `Month` so as a consequence my program doesn't work anymore. (I don't have control on the database, it's managed by other people).

So is there a way to make the column not case sensitive in SQLAlchemy/Python?

Comment: Where exactly and why does the column name change? You can explicitly name columns in `Column` constructor so they don't depend on how you name the attribute inside the table/model class.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but a simple way would be to just get a column ignoring case sensitivity:

```py
meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
table_backlog= meta.tables['backlog']

cols = [_c for _c in table_backlog.columns if _c.name.lower() == "month"]
assert (cols and len(cols) == 1), 'None or multiple column(s) named "month" found'
col_month = cols[0]

all_filters = and_(and_(*all_filters),and_(col_month != "NULL", col_month != None))
```